How can i handle platform dependent dependencies in my code (compile time)?
I'm developing a flutter app for web, ios and android.
I'd like to show a Mapbox Map in my app.
There are currently two packages out there:



package
platform available
Mapbox SDK




mapbox_maps_flutter
ios, android
11.3


mapbox_gl
web, ios, android
10



The mapbox_maps_flutter is the officially mapbox package and better maintained. It also depends on a more up-to-date MapboxSDK.
The mapbox_gl however offers availability for the web platform (through mapbox js code).
My first approach would be to import both packages and decide at runtime which to use:
Widget buildPlatformSpecificWidget(
  TargetPlatform platform) {
if (platform == TargetPlatform.android || platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
  // Android und iOS spezifische Implementierung
  return AppWidget();
} else {
  // Implementierung für die Web-Plattform
  return WebWidget();
}
}

While this works for my Web Application to be build, it does not work when i build for android.
I got some errors during the build process, because i had to add the mapbox 11.3 SDK as dependency and this is something mapbox_gl can't handle.
So I'm basically searching for the most lightweight way to differentiate the build process or handle both dependencies at the same time.
Second approach was Flutter - Exclude unwanted platform specific dependencies but i still get the errors in my build process. So tree shaking alone is not the answer.
Widget buildPlatformSpecificWidget() {
if (APP_PLATFORM) {
  // Android und iOS spezifische Implementierung
  return AppWidget();
} else {
  // Implementierung für die Web-Plattform
  return WebWidget();
}
}

This is the gradle error i am getting:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-24.3.1-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.3.1) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-24.3.1-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.3.1) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-24.3.1-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.3.1) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)

If i remove the WebWidget as well as the dependency to mapbox_gl the app builds as expected.
Any other approach for solving the base problem (mapbox with MapboxSDK 11 on ios and android and Mapbox JS at web) is also appreciated

Just checked out the pubspec from mapbox_gl
https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/pubspec.yaml
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
android:
package: com.mapbox.mapboxgl
pluginClass: MapboxMapsPlugin
ios:
pluginClass: MapboxMapsPlugin
web:
default_package: mapbox_gl_web
Can i somehow exclude/override the plugin values here while maintaining the dependency?
Also thought of somehow just use mapbox_gl_web without the plugin values
